# Azure Authenticating via java sdk in Resource manager mode

Tags: java, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am a Mac user and don't have access to the powershell cli tools. I want to authenticate my java program to the azure in resource manager mode (arm)

According to the docs i have read so far, i have created a app in the Active directory, but I don't see any option to upload any certificate to the application for authentication in the UI. Also, I don't see any option in the UI for assigning privilege to the application for using resource manager api.

Is using powershell the only option to do the above tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am a Mac user and don't have access to the powershell cli tools. I
>   want to authenticate my java program to the azure in resource manager
>   mode (arm)

I'm not sure why you say that. CLI tools are built using node.js (thus available on all platforms) and are different than Azure PowerShell Cmdlets. Please see this link for using CLI tools with Azure Resource Manager - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-azure-resource-manager/.

> According to the docs i have read so far, i have created a app in the
>   Active directory, but I don't see any option to upload any certificate
>   to the application for authentication in the UI.

With Azure Resource Manager, you don't have to do that. The authentication/authorization will be done via Azure Active Directory. Certificate based authentication is for Azure Service Management API.

> Also, I don't see any option in the UI for assigning privilege to the
>   application for using resource manager api.

This, you can do through [`Azure Preview Portal`](https://portal.azure.com). See this screenshot below where I have assigned permission to an application on my Azure Subscription.

[image]

Comment: I have created a application in the active directory and generated the client id and a key for it. Do you have any example of how i can use this to authenticate this in java api.
It looks like the screen shot pased above is under a particular resource group, how do I give privilege to the app to create any resource group ?